# How to cause an object wait for some milliseconds, then cancel the active wait during the waiting time?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I tied to cause an object wait for a period. In this period, the object could be locked and can not process any command. And the wait activity could be cancelled during the waiting period.

Firstly, I tried the following method, it's a simple way:

```
public void toWaiting(int waitingTime)
{
    synchronized(this) // this is the reference for the current object
    {
        try {
            this.wait(waitingTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

It works, the current object could be blocked for waiting, but I can't cancel this wait activity during the waiting time.

So I tried to use Thread to deal with this problem. Putting the wait method in a thread, then cancel the waiting activity by call **Thread.interrupt()**. I have wrote the following codes:

```
public void toWaiting(int waitingTime) 
{
    robotWaitTask waitingTask = new robotWaitTask(waitingTime);
    waitingTask.start();
}

// Generate a thread which could cause the object waiting for a interval
class robotWaitTask extends Thread 
{
    int waitingTime;

    public robotWaitTask(int waitingTime)
    {
        this.waitingTime = waitingTime;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            try {
                this.wait(waitingTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above is not working because the current object is not blocked, unless I change **waitingTask.start()** to **waitingTask.run()** ( I don't know why, there is no Exception). I  know call the run method dose not causes a new Thread generating, it's just a directly calling. So if I use **waitingTask.run()** , then there is no thread could be cancelled by interrupt() method.

How to solve my problem?

Comment: Where are you calling waitingTask.interrupt()?

Comment: You're not using wait as you should, and interrupts are not meant to wake up a thread, but to stop it. Read the tutorial abount concurrency: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html. The wait method's javadoc also has useful information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29

Comment: @Tudor I simply write a new method to call waitingTask.interrupt(), and of course, I had to change waitingTask instance to global variable. But the first question is waitingTask.start() is not working.

Comment: @Miles Zhang: What do you mean by "not working"? Is the run method not executed?

Comment: @JBNizet I'm not use interrupt to wake up a thread, I use it to stop the thread.

Comment: @Tudor Sorry for my ambiguous expressions. I means the current object is not blocked by wait method

Comment: @Miles: so, you want to start a thread whose only task is to wait, and then stop? What's the point? BTW, blocking an object makes no sense. You can block a thread, but not an object.

Comment: @Miles Zhang: What is the value of waitingTime?

Comment: @JBNizet I want to lock the current object for a period, and the lock activity could be cancelled during the waiting time, so I choose use thread to do this. May be is not a correct idea?

Comment: @Tudor It's a int number. toWaiting(10000), like this

Comment: @Miles Zhang: I know, but which value are you actually using in the program? 10000 or something else?

Comment: @Tudor I tried to use a big number so I can observe whether the wait method works. I tried 10000 and 100000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be working. You said that the current object is not blocked unless you change to use .run(). If you call .run(), that means the method is executing in the current thread and not a separate thread. That's probably why you "notice" it is blocking. 
If you use the .start(), a separate thread will be created and the object is blocked in that separate thread. At the same time, your main thread will keep executing.

```
robotWaitTask waitingTask = new robotWaitTask(1000);
waitingTask.start(); //start a new thread, and the object is blocked in a separate thread
//this line will print as soon as the previous line called even before 1000ms
System.out.println("here)"; 


robotWaitTask waitingTask = new robotWaitTask(1000);
waitingTask.run();
//this line will print after 1000ms because the object is blocked in this thread
System.out.println("here)";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You are right, I block the main thread, then I thought the current object was blocking...